# Using (be) as a main verb in this form (be) without using auxiliary verbs, is it correct?

Tags: verbs, questions, negation, auxiliary-verbs, be

There's no doubt that "Be happy" and "Don't be sad." are correct, and "They be happy" is incorrect.

But is it correct to say:

> Why **don't** you **be** more careful?

or

> "Why **don't** they **be** happy?" ?

Why is each of these wrong or right. Is it acceptable to use *be* and *do* together in this context?

Comment: Of course it's possible to say "Why don't they be happy?" and it might just be justifiably correct, grammatically, but I think the more common way of asking the question would be "Why won't they be happy?" or "Why aren't they happy?"

Comment: We don't use *do* support with the verb *be*. [Evidence from Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=doesn't+go%2Cdoesn't+be%2Cdoesn't+make%2Cdoesn't+have%2Cdoesn't+do+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdoes%20not%20go%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdoes%20not%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdoes%20not%20make%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdoes%20not%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdoes%20not%20do%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: (Except in negative commands, like *Don't be sad*.)

Comment: @PeterShor Do be careful about that generalization.

Comment: And from Romper Room: _Do be a Do-Bee, don't be a Don't-Bee_.

Comment: However, it looks like _do_ is only used with _be_ in imperatives.

Comment: @Barmar Actually, not only in imperatives :) We also use this verb *be* - sometimes called *lexical be* - in negative questions and conditional adjuncts. "If he doesn't be more responsible, we'll have to" or "Why don't you be a bit more direct?"

Comment: @PeterShor And in conditional adjuncts and negated questions - where we call  it "lexical" be.

Comment: What dialect you be asking about? For many speakers *They be happy* is fine and (your word:) "correct."

Comment: In American English, although auxiliary _be_ can be used in the progressive when its predicate is active (_Be honest,now._), it still can't take _Do_-support, because _be_ is **always** an auxiliary verb, even when it's the only verb in the sentence, and so it **always** inverts with the subject. Therefore, since _Do_-support  occurs only when there is no auxiliary to invert, it doesn't happen with _be_.

Comment: Whoops!, I meant "imperative" above, not progressive. Sorry about that.

Comment: @JohnLawler But *be* with *do* support is well attested in certain environments and is covered in CamGEL pp. 114. Those environments include negative questions with *why*, e.g. "*Why don't you be more careful?*" and also conditional adjuncts "*If you don't be quick, you'll miss them altogether*".

Comment: 'Be happy!' is not quite as silly as 'Be asleep!' or 'Be tall', but is really (taken at face value) demanding what some would consider the near-impossible (Dick Francis says that 'Don't worry!' is not helpful at all). But of course, 'Be happy!' is used to cheer, to encourage, in a hortative–tongue-in-cheek way. But the usage doesn't extend to 'Why don't they be happy (/asleep/tall)?' as the situations are not under 'their' control, and the 'accomplishment' requirement isn't addressable. 'Why don't they be good / more tidy / early for once?' work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is difficult to find a counterexample, but "be" can be used in sentences in subjunctive mood:

- I suggest/advise/recommend that you be quiet
- It is necessary/essential/imperative/vital that he be here on time.

However, in these examples "be" is not the main verb. The following are examples of phrases where be is the only verb; they are, however, idiomatic expressions (in subjunctive mood)

- if need be
- far be it from me
- be that as it may

More examples with "be" being the only verb can be found:

- Be you angels? And we said... Nay, we are but men! (Tenacious D.)
- To be or not to be?